# Share HTML forms between iOS, Android, and Ionic Webapp all with firebase?

Tags: android, html, ios, webforms, ionic2

This is a general question on software engineering. I have a native iOS, Android, and an Ionic Web app linked to the same Firebase backend.  What I'd like to do is share a customized html webform for each user that can be used on all platforms.  I am trying to save myself development time by using an html webform. The idea is once the user signs in, the app downloads the customized webform I uploaded to the back end, then displays it allowing them to save data to their firebase database.

Is this a smart approach or is there a better method out there?  I've considered using form.io as a service but I like how firebase has offline capability and syncing for free, and html seems more flexible for form design.

My second question is about html binding in ionic. Are there any resources out there that can teach me how to bind the html webform so that I can view it in my Ionic webapp? I have the HTML file already made I just need to make the bindings to firebase.

Comment: In the future I'd like to migrate all platforms to ionic and have the user design their own custom forms but my skills aren't there yet and I already have the native apps published.